# Using an enumeration of CallableStatements as a white list against SQL Injection

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, enums, sql-injection

I have several functions of this form in my application:

```
public long generatedCatId(String name,int age, CallableStatement statement)  throws SQLException
{  
   statement.setString(1,name);  
   statement.setInt(2,age);  
   statement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);  
   statement.execute();  
   return statement.getLong(3);
}
```

What I would like to do is have an `Enum` that contains all allowed `CallableStatement` objects as to create a white list so I can do a simple contains on the set of values within the enum.  The issue I have is that I cannot create a `CallableStatement` object without a `Connection` object.  Is there a way around this limitation?  I do not want to pass around the connection object nor do I want to recompile the `Statement` repeatedly as this will run billions of times a day as part of an automated process.  Finally I do will not be using any ORM tools.

**UPDATE**

Example of arbitrary statements that I would run:

```
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCallable("{Call insert_new_cat(?,?,?)}";
SQL:  insert into cat(id,name,age)  
      values(cat_sequence.nextval,name,age)  
      returning id;
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCallable("{Call update_cat(?,?)}";
SQL:  update cat 
      set age = age   
      where id = id;
```

**Second Update**

There seems to be some confusion around what I am doing.  The flow of the program goes like this:

Process A calls into my functions declared above providing a compiled Statement.  Example below:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("foo");  
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("insert_new_cat");    
for(Cat currentCat : CatList)  
{  
    generateCatId(currentCat.name(),currentCat.age(), statement);  
}  
conn.commit();
```

Notice how the above is both one commit and one compile or preparation of the statement.  I want that statement to be part of an enum or other final data structure that I can then compare against in the `generateCatId` function.

Comment: Can you give an example of two or more 'allowed' statements?

Comment: why not use the string of the query as the white list and use prepared statements after ? i don't think u can avoid using the connection

Comment: @epoch there added some arbitrary statements to show what I am doing.

Comment: @yaelalfasi it is a matter of only compiling it once, but since my functions take statement as a parameter I need a way to whitelist against that input.

Comment: as i don't think you can avoid the connection, how about inheriting from CallableStatement, overriding the toString method, if the regular toString knows to show u the sql and then only compare that ? im not sure it can work, it depends on the db u are using and how they implement the toString...

Comment: btw, if the idea is to avoid sql injections, why like this ? can a user enter in GUI or parameter an sql that you run ? and if u have a list of allowed queries, why let him do that anyway ?

Comment: How would this be better than not having a while list?

Comment: @yaelalfasi Callable is a PreparedStatement so about injecting the `?` parameter is probably not going to happen.  I have outside processes that call me and can attempt to pass sql.  The issue is the part that actually hits the database has no concept of the connection it just plugs along.

Comment: maybe instead of passing an sql it should pass a query id, since it can run anything u dont know in advance anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way around ignoring the `Connection` object, connections are not really that re-usable either, except if you have a connection pool, but they still need to be closed for the pool to know they can be used again. however if you want to encapsulate the `sql`, you can try something like this:

```
enum CallableEnum {
    CALLABLE_ONE("insert_new_cat", 3),
    CALLABLE_TWO("update_cat", 2),
    ;

    private String sql;
    private int parameterCount;

    private CallableEnum(String sql, int params) {
        this.sql = sql;
        this.parameterCount = params;
    }

    public CallableStatement prepare(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{CALL ");
        builder.append(this.sql);
        builder.append("(");

        int count = this.parameterCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            builder.append("?");
            if (i != count - 1) {
                builder.append(", ");
            }
        }

        return connection.prepareCall(builder.append(")}").toString());
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("foo");
CallableStatement statement = CallableEnum.CALLABLE_ONE.prepare(conn);
for (Cat currentCat : catList) {
    generateCatId(currentCat.name(), currentCat.age(), statement);
}

conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

Obviously you can modify it to suit your needs, this is the only idea I could get from your question :)

**UPDATE**

Ok this seems crazy and I have not tested it, but i modified it to encapsulate everything:

```
enum CallableEnum {
    CALLABLE_ONE("insert_new_cat", 3, new Executable<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long apply(CallableStatement statement, Object... arguments) throws SQLException {
            statement.setString(1, String.valueOf(arguments[0]));
            statement.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arguments[1])));
            statement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
            statement.execute();
            return statement.getLong(3);
        }
    }),
    ;

    private String sql;
    private Executable<?> executable;
    private int parameterCount;

    private CallableEnum(String sql, int params, Executable<?> todo) {
        this.sql = sql;
        this.parameterCount = params;
        this.executable = todo;
    }

    public CallableStatement prepare(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("{CALL ");
        builder.append(this.sql);
        builder.append("(");

        int count = this.parameterCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            builder.append("?");
            if (i != count - 1) {
                builder.append(", ");
            }
        }

        return connection.prepareCall(builder.append(")}").toString());
    }

    public <T> T execute(Connection conn, Object... arguments) throws SQLException {
        CallableStatement st = this.prepare(conn);
        return (T) this.executable.apply(st, arguments);
    }

    private interface Executable<T> {
        T apply(CallableStatement st, Object... arguments) throws SQLException;
    }
}
```

It can now be used like this:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("foo");
for (Cat currentCat : catList) {
    CallableEnum.CALLABLE_ONE.execute(conn, currentCat.name(), currentCat.age());
}
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

I don't know if this is what you wanted or even if it will work, but I will leave you with it :)

Comment: yeah I know it seems like a weird question, let me try this out and see how I can get into it.

Comment: Sure, let me know if there is anything else :)

Comment: Wait a second the second part, if that works is exactly what I am looking for.  A way that arbitrary commands cannot be executed against my sql function.  Let me test that out.

Comment: Haha, ok, you will have to play around with the return types a bit